# how to cache feedzirra heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, feedzirra

any idea how to cache feedzirra rss on heroku ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're running on the cedar stack you have access to the disk and can cache there, but your cache will be destroyed if your app is restarted and on each deployment (that may or may not be desirable depending on your setup). If you're running more than one dyno, it may also mean you end up with difference caches on each dyno.

The other alternative is to store the results yourself into some shared persistance. That can be one of the free database options, redis, or memcache. Check https://addons.heroku.com/ to see a list of the ones that are available.